# Prove that if $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, then $\Vert Ax \Vert ^2$ is radially unbounded.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

> Prove that if $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, then $\Vert Ax \Vert ^2$ is radially unbounded.

where a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is radially unbounded means $$\lim_{\Vert x \Vert \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=\infty.$$

Here, the norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is a vector norm on $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is a "generalized" vector norm? How is it different than just a norm on $\mathbb R^m$?

Comment: Ah, you could just say that $\| \cdot \|$ is a norm on $\mathbb R^m$ then.

Comment: Presumably the counterexample is the case where $\Vert Ax\Vert=0$ for $\Vert x\Vert$ because of linear dependence between the rows of $A$ such that $\sum_j (A_{ij}+A_{kj})x_j$ is zero, so even if $\Vert x\Vert$ is growing to infinity in this direction it makes no difference to the value of $\Vert Ax\Vert=0$?

Comment: But since the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, $Ax=0$ can only has solution $x=0$.

Comment: No, if $A$ is **not** linearly independent then it's **not** radially unbounded because for some direction of $x$ we have $Ax=0$ even when $\Vert x\Vert\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\operatorname{rank}(A) = n$, the singular value decomposition of $A$ has the form
\begin{align*}
A = U\begin{bmatrix} D \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} V',
\end{align*}
where $U$ and $V$ are order $m$ and order $n$ real orthogonal matrix respectively, $D = \operatorname{diag}(\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_n)$, $\sigma_1 \geq \cdots \geq \sigma_n > 0$ are $n$ positive singular values of $A$.

It then follows that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$:
\begin{align*}
\|Ax\|^2 = x'V\begin{bmatrix} D' & 0 \end{bmatrix}U'U\begin{bmatrix} D \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}V'x = x'VD^2V'x \geq \sigma_n^2\|V'x\|^2 = \sigma_n^2\|x\|^2, 
\end{align*}
which shows $\|Ax\| \to \infty$ as $\|x\| \to \infty$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** You can use compactness and continuity, together with the linear independence of the columns, to show there exists $c>0$ such that
$$||Ax||\ge c\quad(||x||=1).$$Now show that this implies $$||Ax||\ge c||x||\quad(x\in\Bbb R^n).$$